# How i can trigger a storyboard from resources?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

How i can trigger a storyboard from resources ?
Story:
I write this storyboard and added to resources ()

```
<Ellipse.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="exitgo">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="-168,-579,-195,-631"/>
        </Storyboard>
</Ellipse.Resources>
```

Then i trigger it from vb.net

```
Dim openn As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("exitgo"), Storyboard)
    openn.Begin()
```

But here's the problem, it doesn't work, it simply freeze my application, without any errors
Note that ellapse have some EventTrigger before the resources

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to do this :

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard story = (Storyboard)MyEllipse.Resources["exitgo"];
    Storyboard.SetTarget(story.Children[0], MyEllipse);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(story.Children[1], MyEllipse);

    story.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I posted solution based on what user posted.  
Who downvoted and why ? The solution works perfectly. Give reason for downvoting. SO mods should make comment compulsary if someone downvotes without giving reason.

Comment: It worked, tnx!  maybe they unvoted because it's not vb.net

Comment: BTW, can u explain it a little bit if you can ?

Comment: 1.find resource to get the storyboard, 2. important thing is to set target for your animation which you are not doing, 3. i accessed the two animations(double and thickness) and set their targets.

Comment: tnx you again, cause of your explication i solved my secound problem too, cause sometime i had only 1 animation and it gives me errors, now cause i know i fixed it (bad english, i know :D )